# How can I use range filtering in a Django Subquery?

Tags: django-models

I'm trying to run (simplified):

```
reverses = Location.objects.filter(collect_time__range=(OuterRef('start_time'), OuterRef('stop_time'))).values('id')
mungeable_trips = Trip.objects.annotate(reverse__count=Count(Subquery(reverses))).filter(Q(reverse__count__gt=0)).all()
```

... and I'm getting:

```
ValueError: This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery.
```

I have other filter conditions with OuterRef that work - for comparison, here's the full subquery:

```
reverses = Location.objects.annotate(mod_reversed=F('reversed') % 2).filter(mod_reversed=1)\
            .filter(device=OuterRef('device'), person=OuterRef('mungee'), collect_time__range=(OuterRef('start_time'), OuterRef('stop_time')))
```

Removing just the range filter lets this run without error, but that filter is needed. How can I get this running?

Comment: Can you share the relevant models (likely `Location` and `Trip`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it works without __range, so instead of:

```
collect_time__range=(OuterRef('start_time'), OuterRef('stop_time'))
```

You can do:

```
collect_time__gte=OuterRef('start_time'), collect_time__lte=OuterRef('stop_time')
```

... bug in Django? I'm on 2.2.6.

I also worked around another issue with counting subqueries; I added this step:

```
count_reverses = reverses.annotate(c=Count('*')).values('c')
```

... and I'm annotating this:

```
reverse_count=Subquery(count_reverses, output_field=IntegerField())
```